# How to avoid bundling ReactJs multiple times using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, material-ui

I am trying to use ReactJS as view library rendering on client-side. Also I am imports lots of components from Material-UI as components. 
One issue is that I need to use gulp to setup browserify(for using module in browser ) and babelify(compiling JSX to Javascript). **But I found that if React is bundled more than one time, the UI would have error on behavior and styling.**
According to [this article](http://jpsierens.com/tutorial-gulp-javascript-2015-react/), I setup the gulpfile.js as the following.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var babelify = require('babelify');

var dependencies = [
  'react',
  'react-dom',
  'material-ui',
  'react-tap-event-plugin'
];

var scriptsCount = 0;

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    bundleApp(false);
});

gulp.task('deploy', function (){
  bundleApp(true);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(['./app/*.js'], ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts','watch']);

function bundleApp(isProduction) {
  scriptsCount++;
  var appBundler = browserify({
      entries: './app/app.js',
      debug: true
    })
  if (!isProduction && scriptsCount === 1){
    browserify({
      require: dependencies,
      debug: true
    })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(source('vendors.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js/'));
  }
  if (!isProduction){
    dependencies.forEach(function(dep){
      appBundler.external(dep);
    })
  }
  appBundler
  .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  .bundle()
  .on('error',gutil.log)
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js/'));
}
```

If I run:

```
gulp scripts
```

more than once, the UI would have some problems and error in console.

So HOW should I modify the gulpfile to avoid bundling the React? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `react-addons-transition-group` to your external dependency list. I was facing the same problem.
Here is what I did to resolve it.

1. Cleaned up node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install react-addons-transition-group --save`
3. `npm install`
4. Run `gulp scripts`

I hope that helps.